# Flask restx multipart/form request with file and body with swagger

Tags: python-3.x, flask, swagger, flask-restx

I am trying to implement, using flask-restx, an endpoint which will take both formData (a list of files to be more precise) and a body as json. My code looks as follow:

Multiple files param in some module:

```py
def authorization_param(ns: Namespace, parser: Optional[RequestParser] = None) -> RequestParser:
    if not parser:
        parser = ns.parser()
    parser.add_argument('Authorization', location='headers', required=False, default='Bearer ')
    return parser

def multiple_file_param(arg_name: str, ns: Namespace, parser: Optional[RequestParser] = None) -> RequestParser:
    if not parser:
        parser = ns.parser()
    parser.add_argument(arg_name, type=FileStorage, location='files', required=True, action='append')
    return parser
```

Model:

```py
some_form_model = api.model('form', {'field': fields.String())
```

And the endpoint itself:

```py
ns = Namespace('sth', description='Some stuff'))
auth_param = authorization_param(ns=ns)
file_param = multiple_file_param(arg_name='File', ns=ns)


@ns.route('/files')
@ns.expect(auth_param)
class PreprocessFiles(Resource):
    @ns.response(code=201, description='Job created', model=some_model)
    @ns.response(code=400, description='Bad request', model=None)
    @ns.response(code=401, description='Authentication Error', model=None)
    @ns.response(code=403, description='Forbidden', model=None)
    @ns.response(
        code=422,
        description='Input data validation Error',
        model=some_model
    )
    @ns.expect(some_form_model)
    @ns.expect(file_param)
    def post(self):
        payload = request.get_json()
        # do some stuff..
        return {'text': 'ok'}, 201
```

The endpoint is registered in an API object:

```py
api.add_namespace(ns)
```

My problem is that in swagger I get either input body or file parameter, depending on the order of decorators I use. If I try to pass both form model and file param into one `ns.expect` as so

```py
@ns.expect(some_form_model, file_param)
```

I get the following error in the console and the schema is not rendered:

```
2022-08-26 12:19:45.764 ERROR flask_restx.api api.__schema__: Unable to render schema
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_restx\api.py", line 571, in __schema__
    self._schema = Swagger(self).as_dict()
  File "D:\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_restx\swagger.py", line 239, in as_dict
    serialized = self.serialize_resource(
  File "D:\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_restx\swagger.py", line 446, in serialize_resource
    path[method] = self.serialize_operation(doc, method)
  File "D:\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_restx\swagger.py", line 469, in serialize_operation
    if any(p["type"] == "file" for p in all_params):
  File "D:\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_restx\swagger.py", line 469, in <genexpr>
    if any(p["type"] == "file" for p in all_params):
KeyError: 'type'
```

Is there any way to go around this? I would really like to have good swagger docs for the frontend folks.

Thanks in advance!

Best,
Mateusz

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround to be able to send both types of data from the swagger documentation. You basically need to create a parser that includes both types of arguments, the file would be type=FileStorage, while the other info would be type=ImmutableDict:

```
parser = ns.parser()
parser.add_argument('file', type=FileStorage, location='files')
parser.add_argument('body', type=ImmutableDict, location='form',
                    default={'field': 'value'})
```

#I've included the default just for documentation purposes

In this way, the file will be sent in request.files, and the data in request.form. Then, inside the POST method you just need to take the data from the ImmutableDict data type, which is done parsing it to dict and then with a simple json.loads:

```
json_data = request.form.to_dict()
data = json.loads(['body'])
```

It doesn't look as good as normally, as the body is not sent as a dictionary but as a string, but it's a nice workaround. Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

For the `Authorization` header no parser needed, this could be solve by defining the `authorizations` parameter when creating the `Api` instance of Flask-RESTx, something like this.

```py
api_bp = Blueprint("api", __name__, url_prefix="/api/v1")

authorizations = {
    "Basic": {
        "type": "basic",
        "flow": "password",
    },
    "Bearer": {
        "type": "apiKey",
        "in": "header",
        "name": "Authorization",
    },
}

api = Api(
    app=api_bp,
    title="My REST API",
    description="REST API description",
    authorizations=authorizations,
)
```

`authorizations` parameter will add the section to provide the data for the headers.

[image: authorizations]